# How to adequatly replace Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION (which is now deprecated)?

Tags: android, orientation, sensors, magnetometer

I've tried several code snippets found on the internet in `SensorManager.getOrientation()` - related discussions. None give magnetic azimuth reliably, as `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` did. Could anyone share a working code for `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` emulation?

Comment: Register for Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER and Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD. Low pass filter accelerometer values before calling getRotationMatrix. Keep a history of rotation matrices and calculate the average before calling getOrientation. I got as stable results as sensor_TYPE_ORIENTATION. Of course azimuth values depend on the position of the device (flat or not flat, flat is approximately 25 degree angle between the surface of the screen and the world xy plane). That is if you use remapCoordinateSystem then if the device is flat then the azymuth values are nonsense.

Comment: Since low pass filter accelerometer values is to isolate the gravity component, you can check if TYPE_GRAVITY is available on the device and use it instead of TYPE_ACCELEROMETER.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i replace type\_orientation (is deprecated) for android 4.0.3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003787/how-can-i-replace-type-orientation-is-deprecated-for-android-4-0-3)