# Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION deprecated

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sensors

I was making a Compass app and I stacked at the fact that Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATITON is deprecated and I have no idea how to fix it. Is it possible to get some help. Here is my code and what I have done.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_compass);

    // 
    // TextView that will tell the user what degree is he heading
    tvHeading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHeading);

    // initialize your android device sensor capabilities
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // for the system's orientation sensor registered listeners
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, **mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);**
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // to stop the listener and save battery
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    // get the angle around the z-axis rotated
    float degree = Math.round(event.values[0]);

    tvHeading.setText("Heading: " + Float.toString(degree) + " degrees");

    // create a rotation animation (reverse turn degree degrees)
    RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(
            currentDegree,
            -degree,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f);

    // how long the animation will take place
    ra.setDuration(210);

    // set the animation after the end of the reservation status
    ra.setFillAfter(true);

    // Start the animation
    image.startAnimation(ra);
    currentDegree = -degree;

}
```

The idea is that after the code is executed it has to rotate the image according to the degrees that the compass has detected.

Comment: Documentation says `This constant was deprecated in API level 8. use SensorManager.getOrientation() instead.`. Did you try it?

Comment: You can use my libray at https://github.com/hoananguyen/dsensor

Answer (score 2):

You might take a look at this Answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17477963

(it's been a long time but might help someone)

Comment: Thanks for the late response..I will give thumbs up and home someone will solve his/hers issue