# Unregister TYPE_ORIENTATION sensor

Tags: java, android, sensors

After registering listener for sensor TYPE_ORIENTATION, I cannot unregister it so that it stops reporting the changes for ORIENTATION (software type sensor). I know that TYPE_ORIENTATION is deprecated. It's just the id "3" for this sensor type.

[How can i replace type_orientation (is deprecated) for android 4.0.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003787/how-can-i-replace-type-orientation-is-deprecated-for-android-4-0-3)

I was able to register & unregister anything else (accelerator, gyroscopter, rotation vector...)

```
Sensor orientation = getSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION + ""); // a method to loop through all the sensor existing in device and return the one I'm looking for
Log.d("TEST_ACTIVITY", "unregistering sensor " + orientation.getStringType());
if (orientation != null)
{
    //it does reach here and call unregister this sensor 
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, orientation);
}

//All sensors are registered when service starts
for (Sensor sensor : allSensors)
{
   mSensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, 500000, 500000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: You are checking that "Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION" is not included in your "allSensors" list or you are adding that sensor to the list at some point in your code.

Second: Since "Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION" is deprecated, I would recommend using "OrientationEventListener", the code would be like this:

```
OrientationEventListener orientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this)
{
    @Override
    public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "orientation = " + orientation);
    }
};
orientationEventListener.enable();
```

and to stop the listener:

```
if(orientationEventListener != null) {
                orientationEventListener.disable();
            }
orientationEventListener = null;
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

I hope to help you :D !

Comment: I did single TYPE_ORIENTATION out in the loop registering sensors and it does register and callback onSensorChange when values change. However, unregistering it is impossible for me. This sensor report 3 values for x,y,z planes which are kinda similar to some other type of sensors.